# How to run MSVS2015 Web-project on a local computer

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I went through this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and created a test application.
THen I deployed it in file system, but there is no executable in the output directory, only couple of DLLs.
How can I run and test the application without Visual studio?

Sorry for very newbe question. I'm familiar with Apache, Flask and Node, but have no Idea about MS/.NET

Comment: The article does not says to run code with an executable like .EXE etc. I think you need to revisit the tutorial especially parts where you can see a browser screenshot. The tutorial is about creating REST services using Webapi and consuming those services from within script of HTML pages.

Comment: I know. I have not asked what is missing in the editor, but how do I go further after completing the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. The IIS Express can be used:

```
cd C:\Program Files\IIS Express

C:\Program Files\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe /path:C:\Development\eval\WebApplication1\output /port:9090
```

where C:\Development\eval\WebApplication1\output is the directory i provided for deployment in VS2015 and has the content:

```
15.12.2015  10:46               110 Global.asax
15.12.2015  10:46               729 packages.config
15.12.2015  11:06             1.391 Products.html
15.12.2015  12:21             2.384 Web.config
```